# Cron Job Changing PHP Email Script Output

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

I have an odd issue with a cron job I setup yesterday.  I have the following CronJob script running:

0 7 * * * php -q /wocs/email.php

This is pointed to a email script that I've placed below.  The goal is to have it run the script which calls my MySQL database and sends an email to users saying how many tickets they have to sign.  When I run the query in phpmyadmin I get the correct results, when I echo out the results on the page it gives me the correct results.  But at 7am this morning the Cron Job emailed every user in the database (even users that didn't have any outstanding tickets - so they shouldn't have received anything at all, and they don't show up when I test the query when I run the script myself). They were emailed a dozen times each, and they were sent numbers that weren't accurate and I can't replicate myself.

Here is the code, it works perfectly when I run it in the browser, the only time I get the bug is when the Cron Job is run.

```
$query="
SELECT *, COUNT(*)
FROM job, user
WHERE job.jobs_osuper=user.users_id
AND job.jobs_approverid2 = 0
GROUP BY user.users_id
";              

$result=mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();

$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
                    $conditional1=mysql_result($result,$i,"users_id");
                    $conditional2=mysql_result($result,$i,"jobs_osuper");

$i = 0;
while($i<$num && $conditional1 == $conditional2)
{
                            $name=mysql_result($result,$i,"user_fullname");
                            $email=mysql_result($result,$i,"user_email");
                            $count=mysql_result($result,$i,"COUNT(*)");

$mailfrom = "from@email.com";
$mailbcc = "bcc@email.com";
$message = "<b>$name,</b><p>You have $count ticket(s) waiting on your approval.  <a href='http://url.com'>Click here to review the tickets assigned to you.</a></p>";

mail($email, "Tickets for Approval", $message, "From: $mailfrom\r\nCC: $mailbcc\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n");
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is likely being run by a different user through the cron job. I'm not sure whether this will affect your result, but it has caused me grief in the past.

Your cron command should look something like this:

```
sudo su www-data -c "php -q /wocs/email.php"
```

Make sure that www-data is the correct user - you can check by running `echo get_current_user();` from the browser.